# How to exit gpick color picker after picking from a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, process, tools

I assigned a shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04 to `gpick -p`, which brings up the color picker instantly. GPick is configured to save the picked color to the clipboard.

However, once the color is picked, the gpick interface goes away and `gpick -p` continues running in the background, using CPU.

From `ps ax | grep gpick`:

```
5255 ?        Sl     0:00 gpick -p
```

From `top -p 5255`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5255 oleg      20   0  702448  18096  12744 S   1.7  0.2   0:01.67 gpick
```

**Exact Goal:** A keyboard shortcut that:

1. Turns my mouse into a color picker (with a magnifier window)
2. Once I click, copies the selected color to the clipboard, and
3. goes away

By *goes away*, it could be one of the following:

- ideally, the program would exit
- running in the background without significant resource usage would be OK
- presenting a button to close would be annoying but tolerable

**Things I have tried:**

- Configuring "Single Instance" on and off - did not seem to help
- Configuring "Minimize/Close to System Tray" on and off - did not seem to help, and the program does not appear in tray
- Installing `gcolor2` and `kcolorchooser` - these do not have automatic colorpicking commands
- Using `grabc | xclip -selection clipboard` -- this works, but does not provide a magnifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gpick` has the following issues:

- It does not terminate itself after picking a color is done (you already know that)
- If you copy something to the clipboard and then kill it, you'll have an empty clipboard.

---

**Solution 1 (recommended)**

```
(gpick -p &); pid=$(pidof gpick); sleep 5; xclip -se c -o | xclip -i -se c -l 1; kill $pid
```

To workaround the problem of empty clipboard, the idea is to start `gpick` in a subprocess and copy the content of the clipboard before killing the subprocess.

Create the following bash script and use if as the shortcut program:

```
#!/bin/bash

(gpick -p &);
pid=$(pidof gpick)
sleep 5
xclip -se c -o | xclip -i -se c -l 1
kill $pid
```

It will allow persistence of the clipboard data.

---

**Solution 2** (with a clipboard manager)

The first thing to do is to install a clipboard manager that will offer [Clipboard persistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence), open a terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install clipit xsel
```

Now restart your session to have `clipit` started by default.

The command that you can use in your shortcut to save to the color code to the clipboard and quit `gpick` is:

```
timeout -k 5 5 gpick -p ; clipit -c | xsel -b
```

It will give you 5s to select your color before killing `gpick`.

**Note**: For this solution it seems that a `xsel` process remains after the command but it does not consume CPU.

Comment: `timeout -k 5 5 gpick -p` seems to work by itself when clipit is running. However, when clipit is not running, even `timeout -k 5 5 gpick -p ; clipit -c | xsel -b` does not work. I do not mind clipit running, but is this what you intended? If not, I would be interested to figure out why the command does not work.

Comment: Actually, I have a good reason not to run clipit constantly: my password manager keepassx clears the clipboard after copying a password, and clipit prevents this functionality.

Comment: @Oleg I've added a new solution without a clipboard manager, please let me know if it works as expected. Thanks

Comment: I put the first command in a bash script. When run from a terminal, the script works as expected. But when the script is called from a Ubuntu keyboard shortcut, the clipboard is emptied after the 5 second timeout. Is there a config file somewhere I need to modify to allow clipboard use from a keyboard shortcut? Running `env | grep -i 'select\|clip'` outputs nothing.

Comment: @Oleg: I've updated solution 1 to avoid the zombie xsel/xclip process

Comment: @Oleg: I tested the bash script in the shortcut command. it works for me. The value is still in the clipboard after 5s.

Comment: It works great, thanks. I also understand more about how the clipboard works in Linux now.

Answer (score 0):

## The answer

The command you are searching for is

```sh
gpick -o -s | xclip -sel c
```

However, there are some improvements you can make

## Improvements to the answer

### Not modifying the clipboard when cancelling selection

However, this would replace the clipboard if you cancel the selection (by pressing `Esc`)

```sh
selected_color="$(gpick -o -s)"

[ -z "$selected_color" ] || {
  echo "$selected_color" | xclip -sel c
}
```

### Choosing a different color selector

```sh
selected_color="$(gpick -o -s -c color_css_rgb)"

[ -z "$selected_color" ] || {
  echo "$selected_color" | xclip -sel c
}
```

## Finding the information

Before writing this answer, I only knew about the `-p` flag. However, I wanted to know whether there were other command line arguments which could help me improve the scripts I use. That's why I decided inspecting the source code. That's why I decided to inspect the source code.

The sections presented below explains how I find relevant information for writing this answer.

### Finding the available command line arguments

As for Gpick version 0.2.6rc1, the manual page of `gpick` does not present the command line arguments (see below)

```sh
echo '-'; gpick -v
echo '-'; man -P cat gpick
```

```
-
Gpick version 0.2.6rc1
Revision unknown
Date 2020-12-12
-
gpick()                                                                gpick()

NAME
       gpick - advanced color picker

SYNOPSIS
       gpick [FILE]

DESCRIPTION
       gpick starts an application and opens FILE if it is specified

AUTHOR
       Written by Albertas Vyšniauskas

                                                                       gpick()
```

However, I was able to find the available command line arguments in file:///home/beep1560/SourceCode/gpick/source/main.cpp by performing the following `grep` search and visiting some of the results.

```sh
grep --color -RHInw 'p'  ~/SourceCode/gpick
```

The following is the relevant part of the mentioned file

```
...
static GOptionEntry commandline_entries[] =
{
    {"geometry", 'g', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_STRING, &commandline_geometry, "Window geometry", "GEOMETRY"},
    {"pick", 'p', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &pick_color, "Pick a color", nullptr},
    {"single", 's', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &single_color_pick_mode, "Pick one color and exit", nullptr},
    {"output", 'o', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &output_picked_color, "Output picked color", nullptr},
    {"no-newline", 0, 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &output_without_newline, "Output picked color without newline", nullptr},
    {"no-start", 0, 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &do_not_start, "Do not start Gpick if it is not already running", nullptr},
    {"converter-name", 'c', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_STRING, &converter_name, "Converter name used for floating picker mode", nullptr},
    {"version", 'v', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_NONE, &version_information, "Print version information", nullptr},
    {G_OPTION_REMAINING, 0, 0, G_OPTION_ARG_FILENAME_ARRAY, &commandline_filename, nullptr, "[FILE...]"},
    {nullptr}
};
...
```

### Finding the available converters

The available converters are

- `color_web_hex`
- `color_css_rgb`
- `color_css_hsl`

This information was found in the file file:///home/beep1560/SourceCode/gpick/source/GlobalState.cpp by performing the following `grep` search and visiting some of the results.

```sh
grep --color -RHIn 'converters' ~/SourceCode/gpick
```

Answer (score 0):

To pick single color and output use:

```sh
gpick --pick --single --output
```

or:

```sh
gpick -pso
```